# 5.1 Sound on my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, audio, 5.1

I have a set of 5.1 speakers, and I've been connecting them to my Macbook via two audio cables with a coupler on both ends. I get the extra volume and bass response that a 5.1 system brings, but I'm not truly taking advantage of surround sound.

Is there some way to use an external USB sound card (like the Creative Soundblaster) with Mac OS so that I can get true 5.1 audio from my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

To get true 5.1 you'll need a setup that takes advantage of the optical out audio connection (same port as the headphones/line out). Either a receiver or speaker system that can connect with an optical cable should work for you.

Logitech has the Z-5500 speakers that can do this or Creative X-Fi line of products have some options there as well.